# Show all clients in one site best design

Tags: website-design, web-app

Once a user has logged in, he should be able to click on Clients and a new site with all of the users and their information to show up.
He can then press Edit to change user basic information or Show more, to show a users full profile with some data he is gathering.
Also he can add new Users.
What I'm not sure of, is how to design the site that would show all users in a way that's clean and well designed.
i.e mockup :
[image]

But I'm not very satisfied with doing it like this. Any ideas, or any other website example that does this? I'm a beginner so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the editing inside the detail page? So have the clients' first name be a link to the detail page instead of the show more button taking you there.

Then on the detail page, have an "edit" button that allows editing of whatever fields.

Comment: So on this page to just have Name and Last name for every candidate ? And then on their profile to be able to edit it?
But that's my issue. I'm not sure how to organize them to be shown. In a tabular form or with pictures, or like in the mockup. The database can have a lot of users.

Comment: I agree that the editing should happen within the detail page. If you have a lot of users you should consider adding sorting options (like last name, alphabetical, score etc.). I'd make it a list view and remove the extra space in between each entry. If knowing what the person looks like is relevant, add a profile picture next to the name. If it's not, I'd leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why it looks a bit clattered is

- "show more" which repeats itself for every row
- "edit" button which repeats itself for every row

My proposal is

- Use client's name as a link to go to the detailed page of the client
- Have the action written on table's header and use an icon, which looks calmer

I would suggest thinking about

- Having search per table column - just thinking out loud

[image: UI]